# iReport 5.5.0 won't start

Tags: jvm, ubuntu-12.04, ireport, jvm-hotspot

I want to use iReport on ubuntu 12.04. When I try to start it, it stands still and just gives me this error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/jna4023560596826437553.tmp which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

How can I solve this problem ?

***Edit:*** I tried: `execstack -c /tmp/jna4023560596826437553.tmp` but that didn't help.

Comment: same problem with iReport 5.6 on CentOS 6.6, java 1.7 still not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error seems more related to a JVM problem instead of jasper. Indeed, Java 7 on linux has a feature which blocks code written in C (or other languages like Ruby etc) and linked into Java (the so-called Java Native Interface - JNI) from halting the whole VM if it’s written badly or maliciously.
So, if you're using java version 1.7, getting back to 1.6 should do the trick. But if you want to keep this version, then try a clean uninstall and re-install of java: 
[Uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java/185250#185250),
[Install](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)

Notice that if you're not running on 1.7 , it could be a compatibility problem. Try to match the right jars required for iReport to get it work on linux.

Comment: you are a life saver man ! After hours suffering, I removed java 7 and installed java jdk1.6.0_43, it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu and I did below,

Opened the ireport.conf

and uncomment **jdkhome**

and added java 7 paths (since my default is java 8)

jdkhome=/home/bhanuka/Apps/jdk-7u80-linux-x64/jdk1.7.0_80

Comment: Working for windows as well. conf is In the etc folder